# An absolutely continous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that is not $C^{1}$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is absolutely continuous, but not $C^1$.

My guess is $f(x)=|x-1/2|$. Is it enough to say that $f'(x)$ exists almost everywhere, and that

$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t)dt,$$
or do I need to check that the definition of absolute continuity holds?

Thanks!

Comment: Your guess is correct. Indeed your $f$ is Lipschitz. Then you can check that it's absolutely continuous easilyby definition.

Comment: In fact there are absolutely continuous functions $f$ such that $f'$ is nowhere continuous (regardless of adjustments on sets of measure $0$).